# How do I get the parent row index from a grid cell in Extjs?

Tags: extjs4

I have a CheckColumn in a GridPanel and I want to disable the editable cells of a given row if the checkbox on that row has been checked.  Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "disable the editable cells"? You want to stop cell editing from occurring on anything in that row if the box is checked on the row?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want.  I think I've figured out how to disable editing but I need to get access to the row from the checkbox first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to listen to the beforeedit event on the editor. Something like:

```
cellEditing.on('beforeedit', function(ed, context) {
    return !context.record.get('checkField');
});
```

Comment: Just note you should still perform a check server-side to see if user didn't modify the record via other means.